# Sort error Magento Change from alphabetical to numerical sort

Tags: mysql, magento

I have a attribute called toplist where I import product ranks from another system based on sales. When I try to sort my product list it returns a alphabetic sort order like 1 ,10,100,1000 and I want 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 and so on.
I tried though, to save the attribute like a price field but it doesn't get any better.

Does anyone know how to set the sort order to numeric?

Please I'm desperate here :-(

Comment: How are you doing sorting? What is the type of your `toplist` attribute?

Comment: i have created a attribute called toplist textfield and the settings are used in product sorting yes

Comment: possible duplicate of [Magento Sort Attribute by Decimal not Alphanumerically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22260419/magento-sort-attribute-by-decimal-not-alphanumerically)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, the following may work:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY CAST(toplist as UNSIGNED);
```

"UNSIGNED" means that the field is converted to an unsigned integer before ordering by it. You can also convert it to "SIGNED" or "DECIMAL"